# Replicating user accounts on multiple windows 10 laptops

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

We use multiple identical laptops to introduce new students to Windows 10. It is helpful to have user accounts on all class computers that are identical.  Is there a simple way to configure one system and then duplicate the user account information on each of the other systems?