# Setting up Multiple Users on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, microsoft-surface

My fire/EMS department just recently purchased 4 Microsoft SurfaceGo's with Windows 10 Pro on them. As a part of the set up process for the device, you are asked to have a Microsoft Account. This is all well and good, at least one of us will set this up, no questions there.

We are planning to have multiple users for each tablet (all identical in terms of set up, and who admin and non-admin users are). Is there a maximum number of allowed users and admins for a device? We will likely have 10-20 users and only 1-4 of them will be admins (and therefore only them having customization and app purchasing privileges). We would like to have each user only have to use facial ID and/or a passcode to access because we want security but not having everyone have to remember a lengthy password or something of the like.

I attempted to research if there was a maximum number of users allowed and couldn't find anything. I did find a related question here on Stack Exchange but it had no answers [Multiple Users in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1115200/replicating-user-accounts-on-multiple-windows-10-laptops) and appeared more related to trying to duplicate users. The website I attempted to research my question on was [OnMSFT](https://www.onmsft.com/news/create-multiple-windows-10-user-accounts-single-pc) but it turned out to mostly just have instructions on how to create additional users.

To recap simply, is there a maximum number of non-admin users in Windows 10 and can I have more than one admin account per tablet? Not just a shared admin password, but several unique admin accounts per tablet.

Comment: You can't share Windows Store applications with users who are not logged into the account which purchased those applications.  The exception to this policy is the built-in UWP applications.  If you have a Win32 it does not have the same limitation.  You can have as many accounts, on any version of Windows as you want.  You are only limited to the storage space of the device itself.  Windows XP could have as many Administrator accounts as you wanted.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh... I did not realize that you could have more than one separate admin account on XP, I will remove that. Is it possible to keep a user from having app purchasing privileges through the admin account?

Comment: @Ramhound If you would turn this into an answer, that'd be awesome. I think it has the makings of a great answer!

Comment: It is going to be tough to prevent a user from linking their own Microsoft Account to a local profile if they know the password to both.  I do believe there is a local group policy that prevents a user from linking their Microsoft Account to it.  There really isn't anything I said that is worthy of being submitted as an answer, there are organizations with machines, that have dozens of user profiles on them.  I don't know how to write an answer to your question that would even be considered helpful